# How to access the second site (site_id = 2) from Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-cms, django-settings

I have a project in Django that is monitoring some licenses. For this project, SITE_ID is 1 and domain name is by default **example.com**.

If I create another domain name and I want to make another project that is using that domain, How can I access that site?

In browser how I can access first site and second site?

**E.g:**

**http://127.0.0.1:8080/ is for example.com**

What is for **second_site.com**?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain name is just indicative here, if you launched your first site on 127.0.0.1:8080 (with `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080`, you can, for instance, launch the second on `127.0.0.1:4242`. However it maybe advisable to launch it on another IP address (or domain name) to avoid sharing cookies: `python manage.py runserver 127.1.2.3:8080` or whatever local IP address different from `127.0.0.1`.

Obviously the second project should define `SITE_ID = 2` and use the same database.